# Are there easy to use stock sound effects in Flutter and if so how do I use them?

Tags: flutter

I've seen many guides on how to import your own audio files into a flutter app, but that's way more complexity than I need for what I am doing. I thought I could just

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
...
SystemSound.play(SystemSoundType.click)
```

To make a clicking sound, but I am not hearing anything.

Answer (score 0):

Old issue, but for anyone else coming here, it looks like a [bug](https://github.com/flutter/engine/pull/7783) that was fixed in February.